# How to stop listening to location updates in react native?

Tags: dictionary, react-native, geolocation, gps, react-native-ios

I am using 'react-native-maps'  I got my app rejected recently due to 5.1.1 legal issue . Which says there is some background activities . I have a map and location listener in code .How to stop location updates when app enters background in react native iOS.

Comment: background activity should be legal it must be something else; check some one is selling it infact http://www.transistorsoft.com/shop/products/react-native-background-geolocation#plans

Comment: Thank you, i got it fixed. I was using NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in my info.plist and I just revised it since I need not use location services in the background .